# Не верная загрузка координат меток

Tags: yandex-maps-api

При загрузке файла эксцель в конструктор координаты с началом 9 округляет до 90, а все что после точки округляет. Это только с широтой. То есть загружает вместо:

Импортирую

Широта

92.791729

52.838477

92.808563

91.664137

а возврат на экспорт (для проверки, почему точки показывает в другом месте):

Широта

90

52.838477

90

90

[Вот карта>>](https://yandex.ru/maps/?um=constructor%3A02fe69a23259f987384bcf208ce3d432683ba13215124f91dcafb8dbceae8c86&source=constructorLink)

Answer (score 3):

*Как Вы себе представляете географическую широту больше девяноста градусов? Где на глобусе находятся такие точки? И что это за такая точк**а** на глобусе - с широтой девяносто градусов? Подумайте.*

---

Что-то не так с Вашими входными данными. Возможно, в них перепутаны широта с долготой.

Диапазон значений географической широты: `[-90, 90]` - от полюса до полюса.

Диапазон значений географической долготы: `[-180, 180]` - с запада на восток, через Гринвич.

---

*С уважением,*

*Жак Паганель,*

*секретарь Парижского географического общества, член-корреспондент географических обществ Берлина, Бомбея, Дармштадта, Лейпцига, Лондона, Петербурга, Вены и Нью-Йорка, почетный член Восточноиндийского королевского института географии и этнографии*